# How to know the default value of maximum TTL for Dnsmasq

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I’m able to set a maximum TTL value with Dnsmasq by `--max-ttl`. But I wonder what the default value is if I don’t set `--max-ttl`. Does anyone know about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value is `0`.

The `--max-ttl` option sets up the `max_ttl` attribute as witnessed there:

https://thekelleys.org.uk/gitweb/?p=dnsmasq.git;a=blob;f=src/option.c;h=3a870970b82335dcfa59b5cf1ad0ce765d4484a3;hb=HEAD#l3061

```
3060         else if (option == LOPT_MAXTTL)
3061           daemon->max_ttl = (unsigned long)ttl;
```

It is defined like that, in `src/dnsmasq.h`:

```
extern struct daemon {
  /* datastuctures representing the command-line and
     config file arguments. All set (including defaults)
     in option.c */

[..]

  unsigned long local_ttl, neg_ttl, max_ttl, min_cache_ttl, max_cache_ttl, auth_ttl, dhcp_ttl, use_dhcp_ttl;
```

So its default value is `0` per the C standard.

Later, you can find tests on that value to trigger specific behavior in `src/rfc1035.c`:

```
  /* Return the Max TTL value if it is lower than the actual TTL */
  if (daemon->max_ttl == 0 || ((unsigned)(crecp->ttd - now) < daemon->max_ttl))
    return crecp->ttd - now;
  else
    return daemon->max_ttl;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I've come up with another question reading your answer. I sound that would be counterintuitive. Would it be that each client won't keep the cache?

Comment: See the manual for the option: "The specified maximum TTL will be given to clients instead of the true TTL value if it is lower."  If not set, the value from upstream servers is served as is to clients, which is also what you can see in the code snippet above (first part of the `if`)